# jquery on click every element but

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to remove the class of `active` from a clicked element when anything on the page except the element and its children is clicked.

I know I'm not using the `not()` selector correctly, but this is sort of my best guess. I also don't know how to add the part about the children (?)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content_container').on('click', '.wrapper-dropdown-1', function () {
        //close all open dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').not(this).removeClass('active');


        //close dropdown if anywhere on the body is clicked
        $('body').on('click', ('#content_container').not(this), function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }); 
        //Uncaught TypeError: Object #content_container has no method 'not'


        var dropdown = $(this);
        dropdown.toggleClass('active');
    });
});

//Uncaught TypeError: Object #content_container has no method 'not'
```

I can't understand the difference between that and this successful implementation in the fourth line.

```
$('.wrapper-dropdown-1').not(this).removeClass('active');
```

Comment: thomas, just 1 more rep point!

Comment: @75inchpianist not any more ;) I had to mess it all

Comment: dont you need a $ before the selector to tell its jquery

Comment: @75inchpianist haha, yeah!

Comment: @75inchpianist I was a little confused about how and where exactly `$` would fit in.. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdown;

$('body').on('click', function () {
    if ($(e.target).closest(dropdown).length) return;
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
}); 

$('#content_container').on('click', '.wrapper-dropdown-1', function () {
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').not(this).removeClass('active');
    dropdown = $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Notice the use of `$(e.target)` (the original event element) instead of `$(this)` (which would always be `body`).

The reason it has to be this way is that if you try to use a `:not` style selector in the `on` event filter, you prevent the event from triggering on elements within that zone but not on parents of that zone. An event handler with `not` does not stop propagation of the event, only inclusion in selection. (Stopping event propagation within the captured zone is another approach to this, but one that becomes a challenge to maintain as your app becomes more complex, so I don't recommend it.)

You're also declaring an event handler within another event handler. This has other problems, like the fact that every time they click in that area, you get multiple handlers on `body`. You could conceivably name the event handler and bind and unbind it yourself manually, but it's probably easier just to let this handler run all the time. Odds are you'll want to add to it as you come up with other "click anywhere else to cancel" type zones in your UI going forward.

Answer (score 0):

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/onaxis/2/)

```
$('#content_container').on('click', '.wrapper-dropdown-1', function(evt){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('body').click(function(evt){
  var el = $(evt.target).is('.wrapper-dropdown-1') ? evt.target : null;
  $('#content_container .wrapper-dropdown-1').not(el).removeClass('active');
});
```